# ValueError: Cannot assign "(<SimpleLazyObject: <User: bhavna>>,)": "cart.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django

i am just learning to add ForeignKey instance in table

ValueError: Cannot assign "(<SimpleLazyObject: <User: bhavna>>,)": "cart.user" must be a "User" instance.

this is model file

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField()



class Stock(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size_id    = models.ForeignKey(Size, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour_id  = models.ForeignKey(Colour,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty        = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        s_id = request.POST.get('size_name')
        c_id = request.POST.get('col_name')
        qs = Product.objects.get(id=p_id)
        qtty = 0
        print(p_id)
        print(s_id)
        print(c_id)

        object_stock = Stock.objects.filter(product_id=p_id,size_id=s_id,colour_id=c_id, qty__gte=1).values()
        object_stock1 = Stock.objects.get(product_id=p_id,size_id=s_id,colour_id=c_id, qty__gte=1)
        print(object_stock1)
  
        for ob in object_stock:
          qtty +=  ob['qty']
        if qtty >= 1:
            b = cart(qty=1)
            b.stock = object_stock1
            b.user=request.user,
            b.save()            
            return HttpResponse("Inserted")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not inserted")
```

i am trying add to cart functionality for study purpose but it is giving me error

Comment: `b.user=request.user,` Because of the comma at the end, you're actually assigning a _tuple_.  Get rid of the comma.

Comment: Thank you so much , i was stuck in this for long ... @JohnGordon